# Is there a Rails 4 version of the ActiveJob AsyncAdapter from Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob

Rails 5 ships with the handy [AsyncAdapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/async_adapter.rb) for ActiveJob. Is there a way to use this queue adapter already in Rails 4.2?

**Update:**
I created very quickly a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6b9d4b1405981bbc01edaee637ccdcfb) that seems to work. Comments welcome

Comment: I've also tried this and it worked fine unless you use ActiveRecord.
If you use ActiveRecord, connections used from ActiveJob and the thread who called ActiveJob are managed together.
(Because ActiveRecord's connection pool is managed per process, not per thread.)
Which means if the thread releases connection, ActiveJob's connection is also released even if it's job is not completed yet.